# How to graph 2 column dataframe into multiple violin plots with seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

I'm struggling with getting seaborn to work for me.  I've looked at several tutorials, and nothing seems to be working.  First column is float values, second column is class labels.  I'm wanting each class label to have it's own violin plot.  There is class-imbalance.  How do I get the second column to split up into separate violin plots, and the floats from it's neighboring column assigned into those groups?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = <read files and append [float, str] to list>

data = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['Slope', 'Class'])

                      Slope                Class
0        0.1204778488753736                    A
1      -0.05555463166744862                    B
3       0.12801810567575655                    A
4      -0.05620886965822473                    B
...                     ...                  ...
1126    0.10525394490595655                    D
1127    0.10174103119847132                    E
1128   -0.03527457290513986                    C
1129  -0.035187264760902316                    D
1130   -0.03407274349346173                    E

sns.violinplot(data=data)
```

It displays:

[image]

I'm running out of ideas of what to try.  Most things end up with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Path\Slope Graphs.py", line 43, in <module>
    main(slopes1, slopes2)
  File "c:\Path\Slope Graphs.py", line 26, in main
    sns.violinplot(x='Class', y='Slope', data=data)
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py", line 2384, in violinplot
    plotter = _ViolinPlotter(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order,
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py", line 554, in __init__
    self.estimate_densities(bw, cut, scale, scale_hue, gridsize)
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py", line 620, in estimate_densities
    kde, bw_used = self.fit_kde(kde_data, bw)
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py", line 705, in fit_kde
    kde = stats.gaussian_kde(x, bw)
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\kde.py", line 209, in __init__
    self.set_bandwidth(bw_method=bw_method)
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\kde.py", line 565, in set_bandwidth
    self._compute_covariance()
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\kde.py", line 574, in _compute_covariance
    self._data_covariance = atleast_2d(cov(self.dataset, rowvar=1,
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in cov
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2422, in cov
    avg, w_sum = average(X, axis=1, weights=w, returned=True)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in average
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 420, in average
    scl = wgt.sum(axis=axis, dtype=result_dtype)
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 38, in _sum
    return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where)
TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc add
```

Comment: Try running it as `sns.violinplot(x='Class', y='Slope', data=data)` to let Seaborn know what you want where.

Comment: `TypeError: No loop...`, as mentionded.  I'm getting frustrated.

Comment: Are you sure the 'Slope' column contains numbers and not strings?  If you want a useful solution, you'd need to show your data (as text, not as image) and create a minimal reproducible example including toy data (e.g. a limited subset of something akin to the real data).

Comment: Added the dataframe output

Comment: Check whether the column slope is float

Comment: Can you please create a standalone example. The error trace you show is from a more complicated setup with intermediary functions. You need to show the error trace of your above code, but with just `sns.violinplot(x='Class', y='Slope', data=data)`. It looks like the variable `data` does not contain the dataframe you show.

Comment: It wasn't float.  Once I specified it was a float, then it worked.  Thanks for your help.  :)